# remove item from localStorage

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove an item from localStorage.  When a user clicks on a delete button, I need to examine what is contained in the localStorage and remove the value based on the row that was deleted.

For example, say the localStorage contains the following comma delimited list:

```
contact,user,account
```

If the row that was deleted was the `account` row, then I need to remove account value from the list so that the localStorage would now contain:

```
contact,user
```

Or, if the row that was deleted was the `user` row, then I need to remove the user value from the list so that he localStorage would now contain:

```
contact,account
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function() {
        var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');
        localStorage.activeButtons = '';          
        var active = localStorage.activeButtons.split(',');          
        dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
            updateImages(elem, active[index]);
        });

        j$("img[id$=':deleteImage']").on("click", function(event) {
            updateImages(j$(this).closest('tr'));
        });

        j$('[id$=btnContact]').on('click', function() {
            localStorage.activeButtons += 'contact,';
        });

        j$('[id$=btnUser]').on('click', function() {
            localStorage.activeButtons += 'user,';
        });

        j$('[id$=btnAccount]').on('click', function() {
            localStorage.activeButtons += 'account,';
        });

        A4J.AJAX.AddListener({
            onafterajax: function(req,evt,data) {  

                console.log('************* activeButtons = ' + localStorage.activeButtons);
                j$('[id$=deleteImage]').on('click', function(elem) {
                    console.log('the delete button was clicked');
                    console.log(elem);
                    console.log('************** before ' + localStorage.activeButtons);
                    localStorage.activeButtons = localStorage.activeButtons;
                    console.log('************** after ' + localStorage.activeButtons);
                });
                console.log('************* activeButtons = ' + localStorage.activeButtons);

                var lastRow = j$('table[id$=participantTable] tbody tr:last');                 
                var active = localStorage.activeButtons.split(',');

                var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');
                dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
                    updateImages(elem, active[index]);
                });
            }
        });   

    });

    function updateImages(myRow, myActive) { 
        var rowInputs =  j$(myRow).find('input[type="text"]');
        var contactId = (j$(rowInputs[0]).attr('id'));
        var userId = (j$(rowInputs[1]).attr('id'));
        var accountId = (j$(rowInputs[2]).attr('id'));
        var contact = (j$(rowInputs[0]).val()); 
        var user = (j$(rowInputs[1]).val());
        var account = (j$(rowInputs[2]).val());

        if(contactId.indexOf("participant") != -1 || userId.indexOf("participant") != -1 || accountId.indexOf("participant") != -1) {
            switch (myActive) {
                case "contact":
                    // hide the other two
                    j$(rowInputs[1]).hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[2]).hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                    break;
                case "user":
                    // hide the other two
                    j$(rowInputs[0]).hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[2]).hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                    break;
                case "account":
                    // hide the other two
                    j$(rowInputs[0]).hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[1]).hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                    j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                    break;
            }
            if (contact !== '') {
                j$(rowInputs[1]).hide();
                j$(rowInputs[2]).hide();
                j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').show();
                j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            }    
            else if (user !== '') {
                j$(rowInputs[0]).hide();
                j$(rowInputs[2]).hide();
                j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').show();
                j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            }
            else if (account !== '') {
                j$(rowInputs[0]).hide();
                j$(rowInputs[1]).hide();
                j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').show();
            }
            if (account !== '' && contact !== '') {
                j$(rowInputs[1]).hide();
                j$(rowInputs[2]).show();
                j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').show();
                j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
                j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the relevant portion of the code that I'm trying to remove the value from the localStorage:

```
        A4J.AJAX.AddListener({
            onafterajax: function(req,evt,data) {  

                console.log('************* activeButtons = ' + localStorage.activeButtons);
                j$('[id$=deleteImage]').on('click', function(elem) {
                    console.log('the delete button was clicked');
                    console.log(elem);
                    console.log('************** before ' + localStorage.activeButtons);
                    //here is where I need to remove the value from the localStorage
                          //I am passing in the elem as the function argument to determine
                          //what row is being deleted and what value I should remove from the 
                          //local storage.
                    console.log('************** after ' + localStorage.activeButtons);
                });
                console.log('************* activeButtons = ' + localStorage.activeButtons);

                var lastRow = j$('table[id$=participantTable] tbody tr:last');                 
                var active = localStorage.activeButtons.split(',');

                var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');
                dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
                    updateImages(elem, active[index]);
                });
            }
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `localStorage` be using key/val pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the values into an array, find the value you want to remove, and splice it from the array:

```
var activeArray  = localStorage.activeButtons.split(',');
var idx = activeArray.indexOf(elem); // not sure what elem is, but this should be the value you want to remove

if (idx > -1)
    activeArray.splice(idx, 1);

localStorage.activeButtons = activeArray.join(',');
```